# recursive/auto-executing functions in Jquery behaves differently in Firebug

Tags: jquery, recursion, firebug

I am trying to create a jQuery Gallery that lets the user flip (with previous, next buttons) through 'icons' which contain photos, movies, PDF documents.

My strategy is as follows:

- keep jQuery ignorant of the actual contents of the icon,
- the actual content comes from an Ajax callback, which returns an HTML string,
- if my php-code so decides, a previous and/or next button maybe present in that HTML string,
- if those buttons are present, bind a click event to them,
- the click event makes a recursive call to mainLoop() which shows the new icon.

Here is the code:

```
function mainLoop() {
if (icons[newIndex] !== IFM_APPENDED ) { // tests whether this icon has already been loaded
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/callback/div_supply',
        data: {iconindex: newIndex},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#jquery-lightbox').append(data); // inserts new icon into the DOM
            icons[newIndex] = IFM_APPENDED; // registers that this icon has been loaded
            if ($('#icon'+newIndex+' .prev-button').length !== 0) { // test if the previous button is present
                $('#icon'+newIndex+' .prev-button').click(function () {
                oldIndex = newIndex;
                newIndex -= 1;
                mainLoop();
                }); // END $('#icon'+newIndex+' .prev-button').click()
            } // END if ($('#icon'+newIndex+' .prev-button').length !== 0) 
            if ($('#icon'+newIndex+' .next-button').length !== 0) { // test if the previous button is present
                $('#icon'+newIndex+' .next-button').click(function () {
                oldIndex = newIndex;
                newIndex += 1;
                mainLoop();
                }); // END $('#icon'+newIndex+' .prev-button').click()
            } // END if ($('#icon'+newIndex+' .prev-button').length !== 0) 
        } // END succes:
    }); // END $.ajax
} //  END if (icons[newIndex] !== IFM_APPENDED )
$('#icon'+oldIndex).hide(); // hide the old icon
$('#icon'+newIndex).show(); // hide the new icon
}

$(document).ready(function() {
// Hide some elements to avoid conflict with overlay in IE. These elements appear above the overlay.
$('embed, object, select').css({ 'visibility' : 'hidden' });
$("#gallery li").click(function() {
    _set_interface();
    mainLoop();
}); // END  $("#gallery a").click(function
}); // END $(document).ready(function()
```

This code works fine when I step through mainLoop() in the Firebug debugger.

However, when I run it, the script just hangs. It also ends up hanging when I step though the $(document).ready(function(). There a no console.log() calls which could throw Firebug off.

I suspect there is something wrong with the way I have set up recursion.

What is going wrong?

Comment: If stepping doesn't work (which it should), then try to add either a lot of `console.log` functions, to see where your code starts hanging, or start commenting stuff out in the `mainLoop()` function until it works, and see where your bottleneck is at.

Comment: Thanks h2o, I commented out the recursive click-events and it turns out they were NOT causing the problem. In fact, the .show() method fails to turn display to block. However, the problem has been resolved. Still scratching my heat over this one...

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out though (at least for now, until the problem returns).

Comment: Should you really be combining css `visibility` with `$.show()` and `$.hide()`?

Comment: No, I am combining display:none/block with .show() and .hide(). Not css visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have (sort of) discovered what is going on.

The problem was caused by explicitly stating **display:none** in the callback-HTML. When I do that, the .hide() method fails to turn it to **display: block**.

The plot thickens when you consider that this DOES work when stepping with Firebug. But it fails when running the code straight in Firefox.

I am still not sure what actually hit me...

**EDIT**

This problem went away after I contacted the Dreamhost support. So, I assume that there was nothing wrong on my side, but some setting on the server was out of whack. However, I never learned what the actual problem was.